# In mutex,how the processor(CPU) know which process to unlock?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, mutex

according to my knowledge,The process that locks the mutex is the one that has to unlock the mutex.My doubt is 
how the processor know which process to unlock?is there any datastructure that saves the pid(or)something of that particular process(internally) in waitque?so,that the processor can only unlock the particular process.

please give reply..this d question asked in one of my interviews.

Comment: Are you asking how the threads/processes waiting for the mutex get scheduled by the kernel to run the autonomous "test and set" CPU command to try and get the mutex? I don't believe that there are any guarantees about which thread will get the mutex first so there could be multiple functional implementations of this.

Answer (score 0):

The thread/process that got the mutex is the only one that moves forward in the code.  Later in the code for that thread there should be a release of the mutex.  The other threads/processes that don't have the mutex will be waiting for it so they will neither take it or release it until the 1 running process gets to the mutex release.

Answer (score 0):

> how the processor know which process to unlock?

The *processor* doesn't know anything; it just blindly executes the chain of machine instructions that has been provided to it.

The *threading library*, on the other hand, has been carefully designed to handle this sort of thing.  Also, every modern/multitasking OS includes a thread scheduler that is loaded into memory at boot, and it manages which threads get to run, and when.  It works together with the threading library to handle locking/unlocking issues correctly.

So the question becomes:  How does the OS software know which thread to wake up next when a mutex is unlocked?

Of course the actual implementation will vary with the OS, but conceptually you can imagine each mutex object containing a linked-list, and when a thread tries to lock a mutex that is already locked, the thread adds itself to the tail of the linked-list and then tells the scheduler put it (the thread) to sleep.

Later on, when the mutex is unlocked, the unlock routine pops the first sleeping thread (if any) out of the linked list, re-assigns ownership of the mutex to that thread, and then asks the scheduler to wake up that thread ASAP.

(Caveats:  A real-world implementation would probably be a bit more complex than this, since it needs to be careful to avoid race conditions and maximize performance, but I think this gives you an idea of how it could be done.  Note that in this example implementation, threads would acquire the mutex in first-come/first-served fashion, i.e. in the same order in which they called lock(), but in many real-world implementations, that ordering is not guaranteed, so you shouldn't rely on it)

Comment: thanku for ur reply...i understood what u said..what do you actually mean when you mention " re-assigns ownership of the mutex to that thread"? @Jeremy Friesner

Comment: @sravanthi only one thread holds the mutex at a time; the thread that holds the mutex is said to be the owner of the mutex.  When lock() has returned in a thread, it is guaranteed that that thread is the owner of the mutex.  Therefore, if thread B is waiting inside lock() because thread A is the owner of the mutex, and thread A calls unlock() on the mutex, at that moment thread B will become the owner of the mutex and thread B's lock() call will return so that thread B can resume execution.